# Serialize a Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, serialization, dictionary

I have a simple class like this:

```
class Beam
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm using it as a value in a `Dictionary`:

```
var addresses = new Dictionary<string, Beam>
{
    {"Beam1", new Beam{Name = "B1", Width = 10, Height = 10}},
    {"Beam2", new Beam{Name = "B2", Width = 5, Height = 5}}
};
```

How can I `Serialize` this `Dictionary`? I'm able to do it when the `Dictionary` is like below:

```
Dictionary<string, string>
```

But when I'm using an `Object` as its value I'm getting an exception.

**Update**

```
var fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);

// Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it to serialize the data to the stream.
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
try
{
    formatter.Serialize(fs, addresses);
}
catch (SerializationException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
    throw;
}
finally
{
    fs.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `Serializable` attribute for the class `Beam`:

```
[Serializable]
class Beam
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Adding an attribute to the class doesn't affect performance, but in this case the serialization performed using reflection. If you have any performance issues, create your own serializer/deserializer by implementing the `ISerializable` interface.

Comment: What if I have two dictionaries? Will I be able to serialize these two to a single file? I'll ask it as a new question.

Comment: Yes. You can either create a *container* class (with the `Serializable` attribute), containing these two `Dictionary`s, or create your own serializer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you post this here for future reference for other people who might have this problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735746/serialization-of-two-dictionaries-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark the Beam class as serializable

```
[Serializable]
class Beam
{ ... }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx