# Serialization of two Dictionaries at once

Tags: c#, serialization, dictionary

I have two classes as below and I'm using them in two separate `Dictionaries`. How can I `Serialize` these two Dictionaries to a single file? my Serialization implementation for a single Dictionary can be found at this link:
[Serialize a Dictionary<string, object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735492/serialize-a-dictionarystring-object-in-c-sharp/22735536?noredirect=1#comment34651814_22735536)

```
[Serializable]
class Beam
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
class Column
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my Dictionaries:

```
var Dic1 = new Dictionary<string, Beam>
{
    {"Beam1", new Beam{Name = "B1", Width = 10}},
    {"Beam2", new Beam{Name = "B2", Width = 5}},
};

var Dic2 = new Dictionary<string, Column>
{
    {"Column1", new Column{Name = "C1", Width = 10}},
    {"Column2", new Column{Name = "C2", Width = 5}},
};
```

Here is the complete code I've written so far but I'm getting an exception:

```
[Serializable]
public static class Building
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Beam> Beams;
    public static Dictionary<string, Column> Columns;
}

[Serializable]
public class Beam
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Column
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        Building.Beams.Add("Beam1", new Beam { Name = "B1"});
        Building.Columns.Add("Column1", new Column { Name = "C1" });

        Serialize();
    }

    static void Serialize()
    {

        var fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);

        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        try
        {
            // I'm getting an excepting here:
            // 'Savef.Building' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
            formatter.Serialize(fs, Building);
        }
        catch (SerializationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class marked with the `Serializable` attribute, containing instances of these two dictionaries:

```
[Serializable]
public class Building
{
    public static Building Instance = new Building();

    public readonly Dictionary<string, Beam> Beams = new Dictionary<string, Beam>();
    public readonly Dictionary<string, Column> Columns = new Dictionary<string, Column>();

    public static Dictionary<string, Beam> AllBeams
    {
        get { return Instance.Beams; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
A `Singleton` pattern used to avoid the exception.
In the other parts of the code use `Building.Instance` to access the dictionaries.
**EDIT2**
A `static` property introduced: `Building.AllBeams`. You can use it as shorthand.

Comment: I'm getting an exception maybe it is because I've defined an `static` class?

Comment: Yup, you should pass an instance to the `formatter.Serialize`. Convert your `Building` class to the `Singleton` pattern. I'm going to update the answer.

Comment: See the updated answer. It is already converted. In the rest of the code simply replace each occurrence of `Building` with the `Building.Instance`.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, this totally worked. I can't create an instance of the `static` class somehow right? I wanted my main Building class to be `static`. In the method I will have to call the dictionaries like `Building.Instance.Beams`. I wanted to call them like `Building.Beams`

Comment: A `static` class cannot have an instance. You can create a `static` property with a different name to be able call the `Dictionary` in the short form. I've updated the answer.