# Safety concerns regarding Serialization C#

Tags: c#, serialization

I have `Serialized` all the `Dictionaries` in my application to a file. So when I open this file I can see lots of information regarding my class names and etc which have been saved with the file. 
So is this safe? Will everybody be able to just open a saved file created by my application and see what classes I've used? Here is the method I've used to `Serialize` my Objects.:

[Serialization of two Dictionaries at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735746/serialization-of-two-dictionaries-at-once/22735789?noredirect=1#comment34652896_22735789)

What alternatives I have got to save my objects in my application to a file.

Comment: depends on what kind of application you have

Comment: Do you intend to store the serialized information for long period of time? I have never seen such need though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they will be able to see the structure of the serialized object (maybe if you serialize it to a binary file, it's a bit more difficult, it does not help much tho).

However, anyone can see your source code anyways, just think about [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) or `ildasm`. I personally wouldn't worry about it, I don't see any problem with this.

Comment: That's correct. Moreover, probably there is not one need to store your serialized object file permanently other than study/testing purpose. So, they should be assumed to be secure.

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt the file to hide it contents. So to read encrypted file you need to read it to the memory, decrypt and then pass to the deserialization `Formatter`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you shouldn't be afraid of it.. but it depends on your need.
If you decide that it is important for you, I would recommend to store the data in some other place (remote storage).

You will have 3 alternatives for hiding the content:

1. Encrypt the object, and serialize it (best for local storage and postal) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as0w18af(v=vs.110).aspx
2. serialize the object, and encrypt the file (worse, you will have to handle deleting the file)- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010
3. serialaztion to binary - the worst, doesn't really work - you can open the file in txt in figure out what's going on

So, if that is an importnant thing in your program, I think that the first method will be the best.